# Can I ask for help finding an appropriate school or department for me for grad school?

Tags: discussion, off-topic-questions

I will be applying to grad schools this fall and am having a lot of trouble finding a place that would be appropriate for me. I am a math and linguistics major, and my interests lie in the overlap of these fields, specifically semantics and logic. The main trouble is that my interests are very narrow (and have been so for many years). I undoubtedly want to do math, but I want to do math related to natural-language semantics and prgmatics. Would it be okay to ask for suggestions on schools, departments, or people suitable for me? If so, how could I make the question relevant to a wider audience (i.e., more than just myself)? The question would **not** be along the lines of "what are the best grad programs for linguitics" but rather something like "where can I find people who are working on the following narrow types of problems and also advising grad students".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Rachel and thank you for asking this question here, it means you read the FAQ and I cannot appreciate this more from a new user. :)

Unfortunately, I think your question is still not the most fit for our site. Career advice questions are either too general (and thus might be closed as Off Topic) or too narrow (Too localized). It'd be better to ask that kind of question in chat, I think. If you have any doubts, please ask away!

Hope you stick around.